# Move Cells up based on value

Tags: vba, excel, rows, move

I'm kind of struggeling with VBA for excel. I have a table with products, where products can have multiple categories. The categories that are linked to a product can have sub-categories, which are located in the columns next to it. If a product has multiple categories, these categories are located one row below the product. See pic1.

[image]

**What I want to achieve:**
Every time I execute the script, the current categories that are on the row of the product info need to be replaced with the categories below it, until you reach the next product. If there is no new category to replace, the product row can be deleted. (In this example I need to run the script 3 times). So I eventually will end up with this:

Run script first time:
[image]

Run script second time:
[image]

Run script 3rd time:
[image]

The code I've got so far is:

```
Sub MoveEmpty()

Dim i as Long, j as Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
j = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = j to 3 Step -1
    If Range("A" & i) <> "" Then  
       Range("C" & i -1) = Range("C" & i).Resize(,3)
       Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Hope this makes sense, and thanks for helping out,

Bart

Comment: sub category does not matter?

Comment: It does. So in the first example row C3:C5 need to replace B3:B5, E3:E5 need to replace D3:D5 etc. When there is no row below the product containing categories, the product row can be removed.

Comment: so if the sub categories are different, they should not override each other? my understanding is that you want to make a unique list based on product, category and sub category, right? empty cells in any column represent the first value above them in the same column?

Comment: The whole row needs to be replaced, so yeah, they can be overrided. The use for this is I need to make an import of products to my webshop, but I can only import one category (with subs) per import (so one row of categories per product can be used per import).

Comment: Added some images to clarify. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, this should do what you want:

```
Sub MoveEmpty()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Set this appropriately
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyWorksheet")

j = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = j To 3 Step -1
    If ws.Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
        ' Copy the product name to be next to the 2nd category set down, if there is a category
        If ws.Range("A" & (i + 1)) = "" And ws.Range("C" & (i + 1)) <> "" Then
            ' If you just want the values (i.e. no formatting copied)
            ws.Range("A" & (i + 1)).Resize(, 2).Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Resize(, 2).Value
            ' If you want everything, including formats
            Call ws.Range("A" & i).Resize(, 2).Copy(ws.Range("A" & (i + 1)).Resize(, 2))
        End If

        ws.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
' Reset the screen to updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept it if you feel it answered your question :)